# How to create multicolumn listbox

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am Developing windows phone app. I want to ask how to create multi column list box. where data coming dynamically.

e.g: colg name   Adress      website

```
 branches     subjects   and so on...
```

in xaml.cs i added

then how to displya it in multiple columns in list box

Comment: Is it only for showing purpose or there would be selection ?

Comment: List<data> myD = new List<data>();

 data d1 = new data();
            d1.name = "ColgName";
            myD.Add(d1);

            data d2 = new data();
            d2.name = "address";
            myD.Add(d2);

Comment: ya i want to select that colg name etc nd on its click i m writing some code to navigate on other page

Answer (score 0):

Just add a grid layout with three columns inside ListBox Datatemplate. Here is the example.

```
    <ListBox  Grid.Row="1" Name="listBoxHistory">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
         <Grid Width="480" Background="#e6e6e6" Margin="0,10">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>                       
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
           </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding emailid}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding dob}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding andsoon}"/>
        </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>        
 </ListBox>
```

Comment: This code is working but i would like to ask that this email id password all things are dynamic. I dont know what is next then how to implement it

Comment: e.g. suppose on button click I am getting list of it. but its comming dynamicly then how to add columns for dynamic data